# Python loop to pull items from a list one by one and run them through a block of code

Tags: python, api, loops

I am wondering how I would create a loop to pull a tracking numbers from a list one by one and run it through this block of code. The code currently works so there are no issues there. Just don't want to have to copy and paste every single tracking number one by one manually. I think I know how to do this with a for loop, but the if/else statement is confusing me on how I would use the loop.

```
from usps import USPSApi
from pprint import pprint as pp

userID = ''
usps = USPSApi(userID)

trackingNumber1 = ''

trackingStatus = usps.track(trackingNumber1).result
trackingResponse = trackingStatus.get('TrackResponse')
trackingInfo = trackingResponse.get('TrackInfo')
trackingError = trackingInfo.get('Error')
trackingId = trackingInfo.get('@ID')

if trackingError is None:
  trackingSummary = trackingInfo.get('TrackSummary')
  trackingDetail = trackingInfo.get('TrackDetail')
  print('Tracking Number {0}'.format(trackingId))
  print('Tracking Summary {0}'.format(trackingSummary))
  print('Tracking Detail:')
  pp(trackingDetail)
else:
  trackingHelp = trackingError.get('HelpFile')
  print('Tracking Number {0}'.format(trackingId))
  print('Tracking Error Description: {0}'.format(trackingError.get('Description')))
  print('Tracking Help: {0}'.format(trackingHelp))
```

Comment: Yes you'd simply put all this code in a loop, and then do `for tracking_number in tracking_numbers`, with `tracking_numbers` being a list of tracking numbers. You did not at all specify or ask about how to get a list of them, so I assume you have that part figured out. Actually, if you do have that figured out, what are you asking? How to use basic `for` loops?  Will a basic Python tutorial on that subject not suffice? Or, if you're asking how to get a list of tracking numbers too, there's not enough information to answer that.

Comment: You can achieve this with `for` loops, if you have not used them yet now would be a good time to start. There are plenty of free tutorials online for looping, good luck! [1](https://realpython.com/python-for-loop/) [2](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops) [3](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/for-loop)

Comment: I will have a list of tracking numbers so that is not an issue. I am new to python so I am not sure how to put it all in a loop. I understand basic for loops, but with this particular code I don't quite know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to apply formating to all the elements in a list:

```
collection = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for item in collection:

    # Example formatting rule
    print(item.upper())
```

If your values are in a file:

```
with open("myfile.txt" 'r') as file_handle:

    for line in file_handle:

        # Example formatting rule
        print(line.upper())
```

Example with control flow logic:

```
collection = ['a', 'b', 'c']

for item in collection:

    if isinstance(item, str):

        print(item.upper())
```